# CardView press effect in pre-lollipop device

Tags: android, android-cardview

In pre-lollipop device,when pressed on a cardview,it show a ugly grey rectangle,so how to setting the color only for the card content with out card shadow?

here's my cardView XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="50dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve my problem.

First, create a custom class named `CustomCardView` that extends `CardView`.

Then override the `drawableStateChanged()` method, changing the card background color by calling the `setCardBackgroundColor()` method when card's press status changed.

Last, replace the CardView with this CustomCardView in you layout file.

The only one disadvantage of this solution is CardView can't display ripple press effect on Android 5.0 and above.

Hope this can help you :)

Here's my code:

```
public class CustomCardView extends CardView {

public CustomCardView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    if (isPressed()) {
        this.setCardBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.card_view_pressed));
    } else {
        this.setCardBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.card_view_normal));
    }
}
}
```